# How to display EMGU histogram in chart control?

Tags: .net, opencv, charts, histogram, emgucv

I have the following code example:

```
    //creating histogram using emgu cv c#
    //Create a grayscale image
      Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(400, 400);
    // Fill image with random values
      img.SetRandUniform(new MCvScalar(), new MCvScalar(255));
    // Create and initialize histogram
      DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(256, new RangeF(0.0f, 255.0f));
    // Histogram Computing
      hist.Calculate<Byte>(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { img }, true, null);
```

After the histogram has been calculated, I want to dislay the result in a chart control.

Can someone provide ideas/sample code for implementing this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HistogramBox control let you automatically display image histogram.

Follow [emgu instructions](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Add_ImageBox_Control) to get the whole list of control you can drag&drop on your form. Then it's just a couple of method calls.

```
histogramBox.GenerateHistograms(img,bin); //bin = 256 in your example

histogramBox2.Refresh();
```